# Select option value doesnt reach if statement

Tags: javascript

So I have question I have `select option` element:

```
<select id="item-types__profile" name="item_type_id">
   <option selected disabled style="display:none;" value="0"></option>
</select>
```

And on page load I am triyng to take selected value:

```
const typesSelect = document.getElementById('item-types__profile')

const test = typesSelect.options[typesSelect.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(test);
if (test === 0) {
    console.log('reached');
    document.querySelector('.item-fields').style.display = 'none';
}
```

To console it displays `0`, but it doesn't reach if code and it doesn't print out `console.log('reached')`. I dont understand what could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: `test` is a string: `test === 0` ---> `test == 0` or `parseInt(test) === 0`

Comment: or you can do `if (test === "0") ...`

Comment: `document.querySelector('.item-fields')` does not exist anywhere in your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triple equality `===` is a strict comparison which means it also compares the type. Value from the select option is always a string, here it is `"0"` not `0`. You should cast it to int before checking or use double equality `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition tests for zero as a number or in Javascript that is know as an integar but the variable test is a string. Should be:

if (test === "0")

Answer (score 1):

- Use "==" not "==="

  ```
            const typesSelect = document.getElementById('item-types__profile')

            const test = typesSelect.options[typesSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            console.log(test);
            if (test == 0) { // here 
                console.log('reached');
                document.querySelector('.item-fields').style.display = 'none';
            }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

That would simply be because

> Value :   A String, representing the value of the text field

Simply put `value` returns a string not a integer so you can do :

```
if (test === "0") {
    console.log('reached');
    document.querySelector('.item-fields').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Alternately :

```
if (test == 0) {
    console.log('reached');
    document.querySelector('.item-fields').style.display = 'none';
}
```

The second one will work even though you get a string because we are not doing strict equal check (so `0 == '0'`) yields true while `0 === '0'` yields false